# How can I fix this error when I try to build my project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Error:(45, 30) error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)

I have java 1.8 installed and set in the module settings. But I continuously get this error.

Comment: where you have declared multi-catch, you might see it marked as red, place your cursor on the mark and press alt+enter, do what it says

Comment: I have done that. Similar to eclipse it asks me to change my language compliance level to 7. I accept and the red underlines go away but the build still fails and gives me the exact same error for multi catch statements and diamond marks for arraylists.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project and "Open Module Settings"

There you have to change "Source Compatibility" and "Target Compatibility" to 1.7 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Android currently supports up to Java 7 (v1.7). So I guess you'll need to install JDK v1.7, point your IDE to the installed location of the JDK v7, then recompile your code. It should work then.

You can download the latest JDK v7 release from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html).

Comment: I have done that and I still get the same error. It is located here: (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home)

Comment: Eh, where did you get JDK v1.7.0_71? The latest official version released by Oracle (See the link in my answer) is JDK v1.7.0_67.

Comment: any version of sun java will work. I use 1.8, but yes language compliance cant go above 1.7

Comment: @MowatCS: Are you sure you have pointed your Android Studio (AS) to the correct JDK directory? Have you tried to restart AS and then recompile your codes? _Note: You can have multiple JDK versions installed on a computer, but you need to point AS to the version you want to use._